# Structure pointer pointing to different structure instance

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct first_struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct second_struct
{
    char d;
    int e;
};

struct second_struct second_ins = {'a',10};
struct first_struct first_ins = {20,12};



int main()
{
    struct second_struct *pointer = &first_ins;
    printf("%d\n",pointer->d);   
    return 0;
}
```

And I get an output of 20. Basically, I was trying to see that if I declare a structure pointer, and try to point this to an instance of another structure, what result do I get. Besides a warning from compiler for an incompatible pointer type, it builds and runs fine. 
I was trying to understand how this operation was interpreted by compiler. Shouldnt this be undefined, or may be it is and I am just getting lucky with the result.

Comment: `pointer->d` is exactly the same as `*pointer` because it's the first element in the struct, so it works fine.

Comment: The first element in the second_struct is a character, and it is an integer in first_struct. So, shouldnt it complain when I am trying to print %d. I guess I didnt understand your comment that well.

Comment: Even pointer->e would work fine.

Comment: You are merely lucky, the padding bytes between d and e happen to be 0.  You have no guarantee that they will be 0 everywhere, or even exist.

Comment: The value '20' you use fits in the first byte of an int, so when your 'see' it via the second structure, the first byte is mapped to the first byte of the struct's int so it works. Try using a value like 346 instead to see what happens

Comment: @Hans I would really appreciate if you can expand that into an answer, I am a newbie to this.

Comment: Don't do it.  Expansive enough?

Comment: @AlexisKing That is completely wrong. One is a character and the other is a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that both structs have the same element-wise alignment: `sizeof(first_struct) == sizeof(second_struct)` and: `int e` starts at the same offset in the struct as: `int b`

In other words, `char d` is effectively stored as an `int` in terms of layout. It's simply a lucky coincidence on your platform, and will not work portably.